# Python NLTK collocation for roman numerals

Tags: python, nltk, roman-numerals, collocation

As there is a collocation for numbers in nltk such as `('RS', '##number##')`

I'm wondering if there is such a specifier for Roman numerals which I want to use for something like this: `('volume', '##roman number##')`

If there is no way to do such a thing, it would be helpful if there was a viable way to convert Roman numerals to decimal for sentence segmentation, and then after segmentation convert the text back to the original Roman numerals.